# PHP: Search Directory Tree for File and Return File Path

Tags: php, search, directory-traversal

Consider this workflow:

User makes a request to `website.com/lolmyblogpost`

My .htacces is all like...

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/index.php
RewriteRule .* /index.php
```

Where in index.php im going to search a file tree of templates for `lolmyblogpost.html` returning:

```
/path/to/lolmyblogpost.html
```

So in my master template I can:

```
{include file="{$pathToTemplate}"}
```

**How do I search a directory tree for a file and return the file path?**

Comment: Ok. so what is your question!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @mamdouhalramadan The question is how do I "PHP: Search Directory Tree for File and Return File Path"

Comment: In Apache, PHP, Ruby, ... what language?

Comment: @Tigger Title: "PHP: Search Directory Tree for File and Return File Path". Tags: php, search, directory-traversal

Comment: Try `glob()` - http://php.net/glob - Personally, however, I would use a static list of "known" files unless your site is very dynamic. `glob()` can be a little slow compared to a static array.

Comment: Why don't you know where your templates are?

Comment: @popnoodles It's about building SEO friendly links too content but also preserving internal organization for sanity. I would grep if I needed to find something haha.

Comment: Ah.. then, you are going about it the wrong way. I'll write an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you really want is "look back" support with a default type. Set up your Apache virtual host (something) like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName  example.com:80
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    DocumentRoot    "/path/to/root/dir"
    AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
    ErrorDocument 403 "/403.php"
    ErrorDocument 404 "/404.php"
    <Directory /path/to/root/dir>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
            DefaultType application/x-httpd-php
            AllowOverride All
            Order deny,allow
            Allow from all
            AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript text/css text/html text/plain text/xml
            RewriteEngine On
            RewriteBase /
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !.index.ph.*
            RewriteRule ^(.*)$  /index.php
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

The important line is `DefaultType application/x-httpd-php`, which means you can now get rid of the `.php` file extension.

You can now use a URL like `http://example.com/this_is_a_php_page` and you can also use `http://example.com/this_is_a_php_page/with_a_path_info_var`.

So, on `this_is_a_php_page` (which is really a .php file without an extension) you can use `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']` to check for and vars that are being passed in the URI.

**Edit:**
Added the `RewriteEngine` and rule to push everything to `index.php`. This means you now have a (real) single page on the server called `index.php` which will need to check the `$_SERVER['REDIRECT_URL']` var for what was really requested.

For example, a request for `http://example.com/a_page` will now load `index.php` with `a_page` passed to `$_SERVER['REDIRECT_URL']`. NOTE: this solution will push everything to index.php. You will need to include an exception like:

```
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !.not_me_plz.*
```

To allow all files that start with `not_me_plz` files to be served "as expected".

Comment: What if I am trying to preserve `example.com/singlepathtofile` ? Imagine in the doc root my file tree may actually look like `2012/08,09,10/singlepathtofile.html` ... `2013/01/singlepathtofile.html,02,03` etc.

Comment: This part `2012/08,09,10/` is very messy (hard to deal with). Why not have a URI like: `http://example.com/title_of_post/2012/08,09,10` or `http://example.com/2012/08,09,10/title_of_post` which is very easy to deal with.

Comment: Sorry I meant to my internal doc root structure. All the requests are going through a front end controller.